# How to navigate to specific page on back button event in nativescript 6

Tags: nativescript

I wrote some code to capture the back button event on android when I was using nativescript 5 and it was working fine, but after upgrading to nativescript 6 weird behaviors appeared like:

1- if clear history is set to true, the app navigate to the page then close.

2- if clear history is set to false it navigates to the page then navigate back to the previous page.

An example for this behavior:

Let's say I want the app to navigate to page A when back button pressed,
 and I am in page B so the two weird behaviors are:

`clearHistory: true` the app navigate to page A and close.

`clearHistory: false` the app navigate to A and return to B.

Here is the code:

```
if (application.android) {
    application.android.on(application
        .AndroidApplication
        .activityBackPressedEvent, backEvent);
}

function backEvent(){
    console.log('pressed')
    const navigationEntry = {
        moduleName: 'views/mainPage/main-page',
        animated: true,
        clearHistory: false,
        transition: {
            name: "slideLeft",
            duration: 380,
            curve: "linear"
        }
    }
    frame.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry)
}
```

Is there something that I miss in nativescript 6?

**Project github repo**  [here](https://github.com/KhalifaGad/dm-mobile-app-N/tree/master/app)

Comment: That just sounds like expected behaviour. When `clearHistory` is false, your are allowed to navigate back through history, while true back button from the navigated page closes the app.

Comment: @Manoj I think you misunderstood me, when clearHistory is false it navigates to the specified page and return, I am going to give an example: If I want the app to go to page A when I press the back button, and I have navigated to page B, then when I press the back button it navigates to page A and return to B again.

Comment: Yes, a Playground sample might help to debug.

Comment: @Manoj here is a github repo, and I am uploading the app to playground right now 
https://github.com/KhalifaGad/dm-mobile-app-N

Comment: @Manoj Actually the project size is greater than allowed in nativescript playground, I can't upload it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to navigate upon back button, you must cancel the back navigation first by  setting the cancel flag to true.

```
function backEvent(args) {
    args.cancel = true;
    console.log('pressed')
    const navigationEntry = {
        moduleName: 'views/mainPage/main-page',
        animated: true,
        clearHistory: false,
        transition: {
            name: "slideLeft",
            duration: 380,
            curve: "linear"
        }
    }
    frame.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry)
}
```